# Samsung Galaxy A13 developer mode breaks flashlight

Tags: samsung, developer-options, flashlight

I was using my Samsung Galaxy A13 phone like normal. I could take pictures, run apps, etc. I turned on developer mode on my Samsung A13 unlocked phone and I noticed that, while running my phone in developer mode, I could no longer use the flashlight. I turned off developer mode, tried to turn on the flashlight, and it still wouldn't turn on. I went to the retail outlet that sold me the phone and they could not get it working. I exchanged the phone for another one. I noticed that, at the end of the data transfer process, the flashlight on the original device started working!

My question is, what do I have to do to get my flashlight back? I tried a factory reset of the device and the flashlight still does not work. What other options are there? I tried doing a settings reset on all applications and that did not work.